# Is there a second meaning or connotation behind "you want to use"?

Tags: meaning

On a question I got the answer

> In an AFTER UPDATE trigger, you want to use the new ID.

When I translate it literaly to german, "... möchten Sie verwenden", then there is a second meaning or hidden message in this statement. Using this in german builds a gap between the participants. A teacher can use this or father who is instructing his child. In other cases it would sound a bit presumptuous.

Is there a similar connotation in English or is it just a polite form of "you should do it this way"?

Comment: From your description, it sounds as if the equivalent expression in German is **[condescending](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/condescending)** or **patronizing**. No, it it not so in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this contact, in English, this means either "it is the optimal method to use the new ID" or "only by using the new ID will this work". (In fact, if this is about SQL triggers, I think the second is correct). The use of "You want to"  carries much the same meaning as "you should" or "you ought to" or "the best way for you to do it is" and nothing extra.

I am not clear on the "second meaning" that you note in a German translation, but translations (even good ones) are notorious for more or less subtly changing meaning or introducing unintended second meanings.

In other contexts in English "you want to" can be used as an understated way of making a very forceful statement. A police officer says "You want to step away from the car sir" meaning "Obey me or there will be trouble." A gangster says "You want to pay the protection money by Thursday" meaning "pay up or there will be trouble." But nothign like that is indicated here.